# How to find sum of all objects for some key in array of custom objects in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray, key-value-coding

I have array of objects in which I need to find sum of the particular key.

I have the following properties in object

```
class Due: NSObject {
var dueIndex: Int?
var dueAmount: Double?
}
```

I have the following logic to add the objects to array

```
   var duesArray = [Due]()

    for i in 0..<10 {
        let dueObject = NDDue();
        // Update the due object with the required data.
        dueObject.dueIndex = i
        dueObject.dueAmount = 100 * i

        // Add the due object to dues array.
        duesArray.append(dueObject)
    }
```

After this I need the sum  all the values in duesArray for key dueAmount. Please let me know how to achieve it using KVC.

I have tried by using following below line.

```
print((duesArray as AnyObject).valueForKeyPath("@sum.dueAmount")).
```

Got the following error

```
failed: caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[Due 0x7ff9094505d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dueAmount."
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want the sum of `dueAmount` in your `duesArray` with type `Due` then you can simply use `reduce()`:

```
let totalAmount = duesArray.reduce(0.0) { $0 + ($1.dueAmount ?? 0) }

print(totalAmount) // 4500.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the property of type `Double?` is not exposed to Objective-C because Objective-C can't handle non-class-type optionals. If you change it to `var dueAmount: NSNumber?`, it works.

That begs the question why `dueAmount` and `dueIndex` are optionals in the first place. Must they be?

As Eendje mentioned, the Swift way of doing this is to use `reduce`:

```
let totalAmount = duesArray.reduce(0.0) { $0 + ($1.dueAmount ?? 0.0) }
```